# How can I put an image on top of another image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have seen a few that explains how to do it with absolute position. I'm currently making a Bootstrap 3 site, so I cannot use the absolute attribute.

Below is a quick mock-up of what I'm talking about (note that the play buttons won't be burned into the images below)

[image: Mockup]

Also, if you could explain how to make a similar gradient, it would be nice.

I have tried to use the z-index attribute, but when using it I couldn't figure out how to position the elements relative to elements with lower z-indexes.

Edit:
The play-button (seen on top of the images) will not be a part of the jpg image asset. Rather, it will be its own svg asset put on top of the jpg (thumbnail) image. I choose this way so that I can animate the "play-button" independently.

Neither will the gradient, title, subtitle or "article-tag" be a part of the thumbnail image asset.

The red "divider's" will be its own svg asset as well.

Ideally, I would like to be able to place `<img></img>` objects on top of another `<img></img>` bounding box and be able to move it relative to the bounding box. eg x=50% y=50% for centering. The method should be scalable so that I can have more than two layers as well as having multiple objects on the same layer.

Note: The thumbnail images will be stored on the web server in a resolution of 1920x1080. When trying to use the "divider" as a background image I had a clipping issue:

[image]

It wouldn't expand its parent `<div>`. (also, is there a way to detect user's screen size and rescale the pictures accordingly (on the server) in order to increase loading speed? Like a cookie or something?)

I'm sorry for probably breaking tons of rules on the site, this is my first question.

Comment: *" I'm currently making a Boostrap 3 site, so I cannot use the absolute attribute."* - can yo explain why? Who said that?

Comment: *"play buttons won't be burned into the images"* - what do you mean *burned*..? Could you rephrase that..?

Comment: It doesn't work with the layout. It might work with one screen-size, but as soon as I resize it, it doesn't keep the relative positions which I need. Here's a screenshot of the actual website for clarification [link](http://puu.sh/nUvZR/bc62222390.png) - since I cannot insert pictures into comments apparently.

Comment: You can [edit] the question for adding more information

Comment: So you simply want to have those things in front of a big background image..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding the gradient, a short css writing will be:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #a11633 45%, #7D1229 48%, #7D1229 20%);
```

In addition: I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oronbdd/hzLnak80/) for you for the layouting :)

HTML:

```
<div class="relative-container">
  <div class="absolute-container">
    <div class="flex-1">
    Img 1
    </div>
    <div class="flex-1">
    Img 2
    </div>
    <div class="flex-1">
    Img 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.relative-container{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #a11633 45%, #7D1229 48%, #7D1229 20%);
}

.absolute-container{
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  position:absolute;
  top:55px;
}

.flex-1{
  flex:1;
  border:1px dashed black;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: As for the gradient, I'm probably not doing it correctly, but when pasting the snippet into the image class it doesn't seem to do anything. My best guess is that it renders the gradient below the actual image. Following are two screenshots for clarification:

[link](http://puu.sh/nUwWR/9fa7985863.png)
[link](https://puu.sh/nUwW9/158db5845c.png)

Comment: please note that i've add the gradient class to the div, and not to the image. there is any option that you are adding your code to JSFiddle? or plunker? it will be much easier to help you :)

Comment: I tried to copy the layout into the project. The text "img 1" - 3 didn't align correctly. I then tried to replace "img-1" which didn't scale as expected with absolute-container. [link](http://puu.sh/nUxcj/700e3b27b8.jpg)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the platforms, but I'll try to add it to JSFiddle.

Comment: hi, did you also copied the css classes? please make sure that my custom classes dosent conflict with bootstrap css.

Comment: While trying to make JSFiddle format everything correctly, now that it doesn't have access to the assets, is there somehow I can send you (I assume "collaborate sharing" link) directly?

Comment: Yes, I did copy your CSS classes, should be visible on the screenshot (at the bottom of HomePage.css)

Comment: feel free to send me the project to my email: oronbdd@gmail.com

Comment: @KasperFredenslund His use of the -webkit prefix means this will only work in -webkit browsers. Essentially that means Safari only but Chrome also picks up on some of those. Browsers have not needed the prefix for linear-gradients for quite some time.

Comment: Hi Rob,  thanks for the heads up. How would you recommend implementing the gradient. Should I load a svg file containing the gradient?  Or is it achievable using Jquery?